# Enviar un parametro hacia funcion de controlador Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo la vista de un formulario en el que no voy a borrar nada, solo es para mostrar el dato que voy a borrar.

Comparto el código de la vista

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <h1>Editar Especialidad</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad', $especialidad) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" type="text"  readonly class="form-control-plaintext" class="form-control @error('nombre') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre" value="{{ $especialidad->nombre }}" required autocomplete="nombre" autofocus>
                                @error('nombre')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    {{ __('Borrar') }}
                                </button>
                                <a class=" button btn btn-primary"href="{{route('especialidades.index')}}">Cancelar</a>        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Lo que quisiera es solo el $id que esta vista recibió volverla a mandar al controlador para que pueda cambiar el valor que necesito en la base de datos.

Código del controlador

```
public function borrarEspecialidad($id){
        var_dump($id);
        $especialidad = Especialidades::findOrFail($id);
        $especialidad->estado =False;
        if($especialidad ->save()){
            return redirect()->route('especialidades.index');
        }else{
        return redirect()->route('especialidades.borrar');
        }
    }
```

Y finalmente el código de la ruta

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/especialidades/borrar/{nombre}',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrar'])->name('especialidades.borrar');
Route::put('/especialidades/delete',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrarEspecialidad'])->name('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad');
Route::resource('/especialidades', EspecialidadesController::class);
Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos');
Route::get('editarMedico',[PersonaController::class])->name('editarMedicos');
```

Lo que trato de hacer con eso es un borrado lógico del valor de la base de datos. Pero cuando trato de hacerlo me dá este error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController::borrarEspecialidad(), 0 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected
```

Soy nuevo en Laravel y no se que podría estar haciendo mal. El vardump que tengo en el controlador era para ver si el `$id` llegaba pero al parecer no le llega porque no me lo muestra.

Answer (score 0):

EL error dice que no le pasaste el parametro id a la funcion borrarEspecialidad() no puedo ver exactamente donde ocurrio pero probablemente sea en el atributo "action" de tu formulario (en la vista). o en la ruta /especialidades/delete .

trata de pasarle el {id}.

Comment: si comprendo que el $id no le llega, por eso la pregunta es que debería corregir para que me llegue. Gracias por el apoyo @Ary

Comment: podrias intentar algo asi Route::put ('/especialidades/delete/{id}', etc....

Comment: lo hice pero me da error 404 cuando lo hago

Comment: Bueno no se que podria ser, lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que podrias pasar el id como segundo parametro (como en un edit)  asi: /especialidades/{id}/delete. buena suerte.

Comment: amigo disculpa si funciono lo que dijiste, el problema es que lo estaba pasando como $id. Me salvaste, ya te pongo como respuesta correcta.

Comment: un placer @DiegoUtreras, me alegro que te funcione, para eso estamos aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no la estas parseando en la ruta (delete/{id})

```
Route::put('/especialidades/delete/{id}',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrarEspecialidad'])->name('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad');
```

M